# Ruby. "Magic method" for array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays

Community, how to implement method "m_met" which will reorganize array of hashes (with equal size and with equal "keys") to a form where 1st element will be an array of "keys" and rest - "values" of each hash.
Example:

```
m_met([{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}]) 
# => [[:a, :b, :c], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
h = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}]
h.flat_map { |j| [j.keys, j.values] }.uniq
# => [[:a, :b, :c], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

**UPDATE**

```
h = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}]
[h.first.keys].concat(h.map(&:values))
# => [[:a, :b, :c], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

h = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}]
[h.first.keys].concat(h.map(&:values))
# => [[:a, :b, :c], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks, Priti, answer with N2O-boost =) !

Comment: @SergRa6n *N2O-boost* means?? :)))

Comment: it means "very fast responce" )))

Comment: another assumption? `h = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}]`?

Comment: @VictorMoroz why you are assuming? it is not put in the post first time... We are answering based on the input and output.. That's fare.. If you start assuming.. lots of things is here..with your input what output you expected?

Comment: @Jeffrey sorry I didn't catch you. Is anything wrong in my code?

Comment: @Priti You can't base your solution on the example input and description doesn't say "all sets of values are different", which means your solution doesn't work for all cases (e.g. for the input I mentioned).

Comment: `h = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, {c:6, a: 4, b: 5}]`, description doesn't say "keys are in the same order"

Answer (score 2):

Without additional assumptions it could be something like:

```
hs = [{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}]
ks = hs.first.keys
[ks] + hs.map{ |h| h.values_at(*ks)}
```

**UPDATE** Frankly I would prefer second line as (so I don't need equal whatever)

```
ks = hs.flat_map(&:keys).uniq
```

Comment: `ks = hs.flat_map(&:keys).uniq`  By assumption, the hashes all have the same keys, so that code does a lot of unnecessary work. As the number of hashes goes to infinity, that code will take an infinite amount of time to execute, while code that only examines the first hash to get the keys will take the same amount of time no matter how many hashes there are.  Frankly, I have no idea why you made that change.